# Walking in a random direction

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, geometry

I walk $\pi$ km in one direction followed by $\pi$ km in another direction. In expectation how far am I now from my starting location? Both directions are chosen uniformly at random between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$.

P.S. The answer may surprise you.

Comment: On a Euclidean plane? Or on a sphere? Or on a torus? Or…

Comment: On the plane ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start at the origin $(0,0)$.  If the two directions are $t$ and $u$, the ending location is $\pi(\cos t+\cos u, \sin t+\sin u)$ and the distance from the origin is
$$\pi\sqrt{(\cos t+\cos u)^2+(\sin t+\sin u)^2} = \pi \sqrt{2+2\cos(t-u)}.$$
So the expected distance from the origin is
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\pi \sqrt{2+2\cos(t-u)}}{(2\pi)^2} \mathrm{d}t\, \mathrm{d}u = 4.$$

Comment: Yep you got it!

Comment: Wow a solution without integer programming! ;)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I was not expecting integer programming, and in fact a double integration is very intuitive.

Comment: I don't get it. What if I walk 3.1415.... km in one direction and then randomly choose another direction, which happens to be pointing the exact same way. If I then go another pi kilometers, wouldn't I just be 2 * pi from my starting location? Alternatively, what if the random direction happens to be the exact opposite as my starting direction, so that I end back up at the origin (distance zero)?

Comment: @Dragongeek Yes, $2\pi$ and $0$ are the extreme values of the distribution, and the expected value $4$ is between them.

Comment: @iBug the integer programming comment was a joke, because that's what RobPratt usually uses :)

Comment: @Dragongeek Makes sense intuitively. After the first walk, you're a distance pi from the origin. From there, *over half* of the angles will send you *even further* away, so on average, you wind up a bit further away than pi.

Comment: Can be simplified as result does not depend on 1st direction, setting t to zero.

Comment: @z100 Yes, that is essentially what Ronchen's answer does.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. The question is just a bit unclear, should perhaps mention average distance. As written, I interpreted it as always being one distance, which makes no sense

Answer (score 5):

If we consider the angle between the two walks to be $2\alpha$, in which $0\le\alpha<\pi/2$ (since the case for $\pi/2\le\alpha<\pi$ is equivalent), then the distance between the two points is $2\pi\sin\alpha$. Therefore, taking the integral of that in the range yields $\pi$. Finally, we divide by $\pi/2$, which is our range, to get the expected value of $2$.

Comment: I recall seeing this as a way to estimate $\pi$. Perhaps it is the needle-on-floor approximation?

Comment: This is the nicest and easiest way to do the integration, but there must be a factor 2 missing somewhere. I think your integral should yield $2\pi$ rather than $\pi$.

Comment: I agree that 4 makes more sense

Comment: $[-2\pi \cos \alpha]_0^{\pi/2}=2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Let the smaller angle between the two walks be $\alpha$, where $0\le\alpha\le\pi.$ Using the law of cosines, the distance from where you started is $\sqrt{\pi^2+\pi^2-2\pi^2\cos\alpha}$. Taking the integral of this, we get $\frac{1}{\pi}\int^\pi_0 \sqrt{\pi^2+\pi^2-2\pi^2\cos\alpha}d\alpha=4.$ So the expected value of $\sqrt{\pi^2+\pi^2-2\pi^2\cos\alpha}$ is $4$

Comment: I got a hateful downvote, so I fixed my solution.