# Productive Squares

Tags: mathematics

Consider a productive square of size $n$ to be an $n\times n$ grid filled with a permutation of the integers in  $[1, n^2]$, such that the product of all the numbers along the first row is equal to the product of all the numbers along the first column, and the same applys to the second row/column, the third row/column, etc. We already know that [3~6 are solvable](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107676/fill-in-a-6x6-magic-multiplicative-magic-square), and anything above $10$ is unsolvable (and $9$ is unsolvable as well).

This got me interested: is there a configuration for $7/8/10$?

Comment: For the 10x10 square, I know the numbers on the diagonal. But that's as far as I can reason it, before having to brute-force it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yes, there are solutions for all three.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518847/683666

Comment: Thank you for saving me lots of time, and I still wouldn't have found the solutions anyway. Is there anything that cannot be done with integer linear programming? One day I will understand it...maybe.

Comment: @JLee Yes, one thing: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125404/65277

Comment: @RobPratt my MIP isn't terminating for $N=7$, its running for 6 minutes already... is it normal?

Comment: And how exactly should I implement the $\log$ indicated in the answer, since I'm a little worried about rounding issues?

Comment: (It works fine for $N=1,2,3,4,5,6$) $N=6$ takes about 1 second.

Comment: https://bin.disroot.org/?f28b84c72e7e2e73#7n1RAw8XUt4h3PsJuSsPmc22xznpz6BvowKGeGe93Riw

Comment: Update: $N=8$ ended in 1620.8 seconds and 8327706 bytes used, but $N=7$ is still running.

Comment: Update: **Time used: 6029.5 secs.  Memory used: 12.4 Mb.**

Comment: @SnySmartie I see from your linked log that you are using the numerically preferable alternative (with integer coefficients instead of log).  Using SAS on my laptop, $N=7$ took 15 seconds, $N=8$ took 55 seconds, $N=9$ took 4 seconds to detect infeasibility, and $N=10$ took 112 seconds.

Comment: @RobPratt What is SAS?

Comment: @SnySmartie https://www.sas.com/en_us/home.html I used the MILP solver via the OPTMODEL procedure.

Comment: @RobPratt is $\log$ procedure usable?

Comment: @SnySmartie The $\log$ formulation is slow even for $N=6$ and (because of solver tolerances) is likely to give incorrect results for large enough $N$.